# Dynamically created input. Can't use $refs so how to get e.g. focus?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have dynamically created inputs (list with elements, every element has own ID) for an edition.
All of them have `v-if` to be there only when the edit of the particular element is has been triggered.
Because of that, I can't use `$refs` as Vue does not see that in refs.

How can I solve it? 
I really don't want to add jQuery for that or having to use vanilla JS every time when I need something like that which is quite often.

Comment: how do you trigger editing of an input?

Comment: `@click` and action is setting chosen element as editedElement.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, we have e.g. a `span` before editing, and would use `v-show` rather than `v-if` on it since we still need it after editing, and each `input` is coupled with its according `span`, so something like `event.target.nextSibling.focus()` will do the job.

I prefer `event.target...` to `$refs` as declaring `$refs` adds complexity to the component's structure while the other is just something only relevant within the click event.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to avoid the use of vanilla js (apart from for focusing) then I'd suggest you have to move your list elements into a component:

```js
Vue.component('list-items', {
    template: 
     `<div>
         <button @click="edit">edit</button>
            <input v-if="editing" ref="input" type="text" :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)">
     </div>`,
    props: ['value'],
    data () {
     return {
         editing: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
     edit () {
         this.editing = !this.editing
            if (this.editing) {
             this.$nextTick(() => {
                 this.$refs.input.focus()
                })
            }
        },
    },
})

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        list: [{
            title: 'foo',
        }, {
            title: 'bar',
        }]
    },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <list-items v-model="item.title" v-for="item in list"></list-items>
    <pre>{{ list }}</pre>
</div>
```